# C++ thermometer

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a school assignment in C++, which is my first assignment in C++. I only did Python, so I'm a little lost. I'm pretty much a beginner in coding, so I will appreciate any help.

The assignment is to write a program that will display a "thermometer". The temperatures are given in an array. Positive numbers are displayed as `|*****` (this would be for number 5), and negative numbers are `*****|` (for -5), if the value is 0 then it's only `|`. If there's a value missing, there would be `no_value` and the output for that would be the same as the one before (if the number before `no_value` is 4 then it's `|****`).

In the output the `|` should be representing 0, so they are creating a line.

This is my code so far:

```
int main() {
    constexpr int no_value = -999;
    constexpr int temperatures[] { 10, 12, no_value, no_value, 20, 14, 6, -1, -5, 0, no_value, 1, -3 };
    int previous_value = 0;

    while (cin >> temperatures) {

        if (temperatures == no_value) {  //for no_value
            temperatures = previous_value;
        }
        else {
            previous_value = temperatures;
        }
        if (temperatures > 0) {   // for positive value
            cout << "|";
            for (int i = 0; i < temperatures; i++) {
                cout << "*";
            }
        }
        else if (temperatures < 0) {    //for negative value
            for (int i = 0; i < -temperatures; i++) {
                cout << "*";
            }
            cout << "|";
        }
        else {   //for value == 0
            cout << "|";
        }
        cout << endl;
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

There are operator errors, as well as some incompatible operand types. It also tells me that on line 13 (after the first `if`) the expression must be a modifiable lvalue.

I also don't know how to make the `|` to be on the same position every time. I was thinking of using the biggest absolute value of the negative number to make space, but I don't know how to write that.

I would appreciate any help, and some explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `while (cin >> temperatures)` will not work. For one thing, `temperatures` is `constexpr` so it can't be modified. And two, because there is no `operator>>` to read in a whole array of values.  For that matter, nothing in your instructions says that you need to read input from the user at all, so you shouldn't even be using `cin` in this program.

Also, all of your `if`s and `for`s are trying to compare the whole array to a single value, which will never work, either.

I think you need to learn what an array actually is, and what you can and can't do with an array.

Everything your program is trying to do with the array as a whole, looks like it should be doing with *each value* of the array instead.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    constexpr int no_value = -999;
    constexpr int temperatures[] { 10, 12, no_value, no_value, 20, 14, 6, -1, -5, 0, no_value, 1, -3 };
    int previous_value = 0;

    for (int temperature : temperatures) {

        if (temperature == no_value) {  //for no_value
            temperature = previous_value;
        }
        else {
            previous_value = temperature;
        }

        if (temperature > 0) {   // for positive value
            cout << '|';
            for (int i = 0; i < temperature; ++i) {
                cout << '*';
            }
        }
        else if (temperature < 0) {    //for negative value
            temperature = -temperature;
            for (int i = 0; i < temperature; ++i) {
                cout << '*';
            }
            cout << '|';
        }
        else {   //for value == 0
            cout << '|';
        }
        cout << '\n';
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
|**********
|************
|************
|************
|********************
|**************
|******
*|
*****|
|
|
|*
***|
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/QW6VrW)

Then, to line up the `|`s, that is just a matter of adding the appropriate amount of whitespace on each side of the `|` as needed, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    constexpr int no_value = -999;
    constexpr int temperatures[] { 10, 12, no_value, no_value, 20, 14, 6, -1, -5, 0, no_value, 1, -3 };
    int previous_value = 0;
    int max_value = 0;

    for (int temperature : temperatures) {
        if (temperature != no_value) {
            max_value = max(max_value, abs(temperature));
        }
    }

    for (int temperature : temperatures) {

        if (temperature == no_value) {
            temperature = previous_value;
        }
        else {
            previous_value = temperature;
        }

        if (temperature > 0) {   // for positive value
            for (int i = 0; i < max_value; ++i) {
                cout << ' ';
            }
            cout << '|';
            for (int i = 0; i < temperature; ++i) {
                cout << '*';
            }
            for (int i = temperature; i < max_value; ++i) {
                cout << ' ';
            }
        }
        else if (temperature < 0) {    //for negative value
            temperature = abs(temperature);
            for(int i = max_value; i > temperature; --i) {
                cout << ' ';
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < temperature; ++i) {
                cout << '*';
            }
            cout << '|';
            for (int i = 0; i < max_value; ++i) {
                cout << ' ';
            }
        }
        else {   //for value == 0
            for(int i = 0; i < max_value; ++i) {
                cout << ' ';
            }
            cout << '|';
            for(int i = 0; i < max_value; ++i) {
                cout << ' ';
            }
        }
        cout << '\n';
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
                    |**********          
                    |************        
                    |************        
                    |************        
                    |********************
                    |**************      
                    |******              
                   *|                    
               *****|                    
                    |                    
                    |                    
                    |*                   
                 ***|
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/Ez5zAg)

Which can be taken a step further by replacing the manual print loops with the `std::setw()` and `std::setfill()` I/O manipulators, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    constexpr int no_value = -999;
    constexpr int temperatures[] { 10, 12, no_value, no_value, 20, 14, 6, -1, -5, 0, no_value, 1, -3 };
    int previous_value = 0;
    int max_value = 0;

    for (int temperature : temperatures) {
        if (temperature != no_value) {
            max_value = max(max_value, abs(temperature));
        }
    }

    for (int temperature : temperatures) {

        if (temperature == no_value) {
            temperature = previous_value;
        }
        else {
            previous_value = temperature;
        }

        if (temperature > 0) {   // for positive value
            cout << setw(max_value) << setfill(' ') << ' ';
            cout << '|';
            cout << setw(temperature) << setfill('*') << '*';
            if (temperature < max_value) {
                cout << setw(max_value-temperature) << setfill(' ') << ' ';
            }
        }
        else if (temperature < 0) {    //for negative value
            temperature = abs(temperature);
            if (temperature < max_value) {
                cout << setw(max_value-temperature) << setfill(' ') << ' ';
            }
            cout << setw(temperature) << setfill('*') << '*';
            cout << '|';
            cout << setw(max_value) << setfill(' ') << ' ';
        }
        else {   //for value == 0
            cout << setw(max_value) << setfill(' ') << ' ';
            cout << '|';
            cout << setw(max_value) << setfill(' ') << ' ';
        }
        cout << '\n';
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
                    |**********          
                    |************        
                    |************        
                    |************        
                    |********************
                    |**************      
                    |******              
                   *|                    
               *****|                    
                    |                    
                    |                    
                    |*                   
                 ***|
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/xWYL6E)

Answer (score 0):

First a look at the errors:

- ```
  |     while (cin >> temperatures) {
  ```

  `error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::istream' {aka 'std::basic_istream<char>'} and 'const int [13]')`
  You are trying to read values from `std::cin` directly into an array of `int`s, but there is no `operator>>` overload supporting that.
- ```
  |         if (temperatures == no_value) {  //for no_value
  |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  `error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer`
  `temperatures` decays into a pointer to the first element (a `const int*`) in the array. You can't compare a `const int*` with an `int`.
- ```
  |             temperatures = previous_value;
  ```

  `error: assignment of read-only variable 'temperatures'`
  `temperatures` is declared to be a constant so you can't make changes to it. Even if it *had* been non-`const` could you assign to it. Arrays do not have an assignment operator and `previous_value` is not even an array.
- ```
  |             previous_value = temperatures;
  |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~
  |                              |
  |                              const int*
  ```

  `error: invalid conversion from 'const int*' to 'int'`
  Assigning a `const int*` (again, `temperatures` decays into a pointer to the first element in the array) to an `int` is not supported either.
- ```
  |         if (temperatures > 0) {   // for positive value
  |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
  ```

  `error: ordered comparison of pointer with integer zero ('const int*' and 'int')` (and the same error occurs when checking for a negative value)
  Here you are trying to compare the `const int*` with an `int`. Not supported.
- ```
  |             for (int i = 0; i < temperatures; i++) {
  |                             ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  `error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer`
  ... and it's a similar issue here.
- ```
  |             for (int i = 0; i < -temperatures; i++) {
  |                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  `error: wrong type argument to unary minus`
  And negating a `const int*` doesn't work either.

---

I suggest that you create a helper function that creates `std::string`s representing the different thermometers. In order to display it correctly, you would first need to find the minimum temperature in the array, just in case all temperatures are positive - and you still want to display the zero-line. When the minimum temperature is found, the helper function could look like below. The first argument to `std::string` is a count and the second is the character you want, so you can make a string of 5 asterisks with `std::string(5, '*')` for example:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

std::string get_thermometer(int temp, int min) {
    // how much to fill before the 0-line:
    std::string result(std::min(temp, 0) - min, ' ');

    // if negative temp, add asterisks:    
    if(temp < 0) result += std::string(-temp, '*');
    
    result += '|'; // 0-line
    
    // if positive temp, add asterisks:
    if(temp > 0) result += std::string(temp, '*');

    return result;
}
```

Finding the minimum temperature can be done with the standard algorithm [`std::min_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element). You can also find both the minimum and maximum elements at the same time using [`std::minmax_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) which I've used to be able to display the temperature range in the array. Both algorithms return *iterators*, which is a pointer-like (or an actual pointer) to the found element. By dereferencing (`*iterator`) an iterator (pointer), you'll get a reference to the actual value that the iterator points at.

```cpp
int main() {
    constexpr int no_value = -999;
    constexpr int temperatures[]{10, 12, no_value, no_value, 20, 14, 6,
                                 -1, -5, 0,        no_value, 1,  -3};

    // get iterators to the min and max values (skipping the no_value elements):
    auto [minit, maxit] = std::minmax_element(
        std::begin(temperatures), std::end(temperatures),
        [](int lhs, int rhs) { return lhs != no_value && lhs < rhs; });

    // make sure 0 is represented on the thermometer even if only negative or
    // only positive temperatures are present in the array:
    int min = std::min(*minit, 0);
    int max = std::max(*maxit, 0);

    std::cout << "temperature range: [" << *minit << ", " << *maxit << "]\n";
    std::cout << "thermometer range: [" << min << ", " << max << "]\n";

    for (std::string tempstr; int temp : temperatures) {
        if (temp != no_value) tempstr = get_thermometer(temp, min);
        // else keep the old tempstr

        std::cout << tempstr << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
temperature range: [-5, 20]
thermometer range: [-5, 20]
     |**********
     |************
     |************
     |************
     |********************
     |**************
     |******
    *|
*****|
     |
     |
     |*
  ***|
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3PGjancE5)